# How to call custom instance Java method in Datomic query?

Tags: java, datomic

I am very new to Datomic DB, I am trying to call my custom method inside query.
Static methods are working fine.

```
Peer.query("[:find ?r ?k" +
    " :where "
    +"[?name :solar/planet ?r] "
    + "[(com.mypack.production.CustomFilter/ToUpper \"pawan\") ?k ]]"
    ,
    conn.db());
```

How can I call instance method of class `CustomFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call instance methods with the form: `(.methodName obj …)`

The Datomic Docs provide additional discussion of calling java instance methods:
http://docs.datomic.com/query.html#calling-instance-methods

Best,
Marshall

Comment: Where i can specify my class name